# appcfg.py: error: no such option: --passin | after updating Google App Engine Launcher

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api-php-client

Ive just upgraded the Google App Engine Launcher (for PHP) and now I'm getting this error message.

Any ideas what why that ocurred and how to fix it?

UPDATE1: right now it is only working in console like this:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" "update" "D:\route\to\application"
```

And I can't find the way to update the parameter in the Google Engine Launcher. Any thoughts?

UPDATE2: ok, it seems that the issue has to do with the migration to oAuth2. So, the new question is: how can I make the Google Engine no to use "--passin"? Because I uninstalled (and remove any trace of it) and then reinstalled, but it insist in using the "--passing" parameter, making it completely useless.

UPDATE3: the issue was that I was using Google SDK and updated the Engine using "GoogleAppEngine-1.9.24.msi". And it was not updating the shortcut, so I was still using some data from the SDK.

Solution: remove the Google Cloud SDK and install again. Then install the App Engine. And it worked.

Comment: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/google-appengine/154nepq4cm/oauth-2-0-will-become-the-default-authentication-mechanism-for-deploying-to-app-engine

Comment: I can see that. In fact, in the prev release the launcher was forwarding to the browser to validate credentials (oAuth2). But with this one (1.9.24) it just stopped working altogether.

Comment: In all the App Engine SDKs, authentication for app deployment is now exclusively through OAuth2. Authentication using an email address and password is no longer supported and the --no_oauth2 flag is no longer available: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes

Comment: I can see the oAuth2 issue. But the Engine Launcher keeps using that. Does anyone know how to make the Engine Launcher to use oAuth2 instead of asking for username/password?

Comment: It is a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: remove the Google Cloud SDK and install again. Then install the App Engine. And it worked.