# Phpstorm can't upload to google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, phpstorm

After following the quickstart for setting up google-app-engine integration into phpstorm here https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Getting+Started+with+PhpStorm+as+Google+App+Engine+PHP+IDE

I can't upload code app engine and i get this error message. Is there anywhere in the settings of phpstorm something i shuld change tomake it work?

> ```
> /usr/bin/python /path/to/google_appengine/appcfg.py -e account@gmail.com --passin --no_cookies update .
> Usage: appcfg.py [options] <action>
>
> appcfg.py: error: no such option: --passin
>
> Process finished with exit code 2
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [appcfg.py: error: no such option: --passin | after updating Google App Engine Launcher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542024/appcfg-py-error-no-such-option-passin-after-updating-google-app-engine-la)

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains are a bit behind the updates in the SDK's `appcfg.py` changes and don't have support for configuring/customizing the upload arguments - I had a similar issue with PyCharm.

My recommendation is to perform the upload from the terminal, using directly `appcfg.py` following the SDK instructions, instead of uploading from the IDE.

Comment: thanks, also it seems that upload through password/login is deprecated on google app engine, i used oauth and it worked from the ide.